# C Functions homework build errors with passing arrays Help needed Beginner problems

Tags: c, debugging

I have been searching the net trying to resolve my build errors. I'm pretty sure once I fix these that my program will function but as I have yet been able to compile my code it makes it hard to test.

Any advice would be appreciated and yes this is homework. I'm new to C and I know I am probably making stupid mistakes. I will take all responses as a learning opportunity. The code is as follows. After the errors are posted.

```
    // Program will take user input for student names and provide functions in
    //   order to sort  by first name, by last name
    // by score and a menu function.

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    // Prototypes for functions
    int menu();
    void searchLast(char [][21], char [][21],float [], int);
    void searchFirst(char [][21], char [][21],float [], int);
    void sortLast(char [][21], char [][21],float [], int);
    void sortScore(char [][21], char [][21],float [], int);
    void printRecords(char [][21], char [][21],float [], int);

    int main()
    {
    int j,NumOfRecords, k = 0;
    char FirstN[15][21],LastN[15][21];
    float Score[15];
    int select = 0;

        // Asking for the number of records the students to add
    printf("How many records would you like to enter, minimum of 5, max of 15? "); G
    scanf("%d",&NumOfRecords);
    for( k = 0; k < NumOfRecords; k++) // Loop to take user input and save in appropriate 
                                           // array location 
    { 
        for(j=0;j<21;j++)
    {
        scanf("First name:  %s", &FirstN[k][j]);
        scanf("   Last Name: %s", &LastN[k][j]);
        scanf("   Score: %f", &Score[k]);
            printf("\n");
    }
    }


    select = menu();  // Calling menu function to assign selection to call the next function
printf("%d",select);  // checking to see that selection was passed to 'select'
while (select != 0)   // Sentinel loop to provide user with options to modify array output 
{
    if (select == 1)  // prints all records
    {
        printRecords(FirstN,LastN,Score,NumOfRecords);
    }
    if (select == 2) //Searches for First name and prints associated records
    {
        searchFirst(FirstN,LastN,Score,NumOfRecords);
    }
    if (select == 3) // Searches for last name and prints associated records
    {
        searchLast(FirstN,LastN,Score,NumOfRecords);
    }
    if (select == 4)  // Sorts records by score and prints associated records
    {
        sortScore(FirstN,LastN,Score,NumOfRecords);
    }
    if (select == 5)  // Sorts by last name and prints associated records
    {
        sortLast(FirstN,LastN,Score,NumOfRecords);
    }
    if (select == 0) // Exits program
        break;

    select = menu();
}

    return 0; 

    }

    int menu() // The menu function
    {
    int num;
    printf("Menu Options \n \n");
    printf("Print Records (press 1) \n");
    printf("Search by first name (press 2) \n");
    printf("Search by last name (press 3) \n");
    printf("Sort by score (press 4) \n");
    printf("Sort by last name (press 5) \n");
    printf("Exit the program (press 0) \n");
    printf("Please enter option number: ");
    scanf("%d", num); // Takes the selection to be passed out of the function
    return num; // Returns the selection to main
    }
    void searchLast(char FirstName[][21],char LastName[][21], float Scores[],int NumOfRecords)
    { 
    int j;
    char Lname[1][21];
    printf("Please enter last name to search for");
    for (j=0;j<20;j++)
{
    scanf("%s",Lname[0][j]);
}
    for(j=0;j<NumOfRecords;j++)
    {
    if(Lname[0] == LastName[j])
    {
        printf("%s %s %f",FirstName[j],LastName[j],Scores[j]);
    }
        }

    }


    void searchFirst(char FirstName[][21],char LastName[][21], float Scores[],int NumOfRecords)

    {
    int j;
    char Fname[1][21];
    printf("Please enter last name to search for");
    for (j=0;j<20;j++)
{
    scanf("%s",Fname[0][j]);
}
    for(j=0;j<NumOfRecords;j++)
{
    if(Fname[0] == FirstName[j])
    {
        printf("%s %s %f",FirstName[j],LastName[j],Scores[j]);
    }
} 
    }
    void sortLast(char FirstName[][21],char LastName[][21], float Scores[],int NumOfRecords)
    {
    int j,x = 0;
    int k;
    for(j = 0; LastName[j] < LastName[j+1] ; j++)
    {
    for(k = (j+1) ; k < NumOfRecords; k++)
        if (LastName[j] < LastName[k])
        {
            float temp = 0; // function attempts to sort Arrays saving string 
            char tempFirst; // values in a veriable to then be reassigned to 
            char tempLast;  // appropriate Array index.
            temp = Scores[j];
            Scores[j] = Scores[k];
            Scores[k] = temp;
            tempLast = LastName[j];
            LastName[j] = LastName[k];
            LastName[k] = tempLast;
            tempFirst = FirstName[j]
            FirstName[j] = FirstName[k];
            FirstName[k] = tempFirst;
    }
    void sortScore(char FirstName[15][21],char LastName[15][21], float Scores[],int NumOfRecords)

    {

int j,x = 0;
int k;
for(j = 0; Scores[j] < Scores[j+1] ; j++)
{
    for(k = (j+1) ; k < NumOfRecords; k++)
        if (Scores[j] < Scores[k])
        {
            float temp = 0;
            char tempFirst;
            char tempLast;
            temp = Scores[j];
            Scores[j] = Scores[k];
            Scores[k] = temp;
            tempLast = LastName[j];
            LastName[j] = LastName[k];
            LastName[k] = tempLast;
            tempFirst = FirstName[j]
            FirstName[j] = FirstName[k];
            FirstName[k] = tempFirst;
        }


}
printRecords(FirstName,LastName,Scores,NumOfRecords);
    }
    void printRecords(char FirstName[][21],char LastName[][21], float Scores[],int NumOfRecords)
    {
    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < NumOfRecords ; j++)
    {
    printf("%s %s %f \n",FirstName[j],LastName[j],Scores[j]);

    }
    }
```

//Errors:

```
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(139): warning C4047: '=' : 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(140): error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(141): warning C4047: '=' : 'char [21]' differs in levels of indirection from 'char'
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(141): error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(143): warning C4047: '=' : 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(143): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'FirstName'
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(143): error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(144): warning C4047: '=' : 'char [21]' differs in levels of indirection from 'char'
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(144): error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(146): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(150): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(162): warning C4047: '=' : 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(163): error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(164): warning C4047: '=' : 'char [21]' differs in levels of indirection from 'char'
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(164): error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(166): warning C4047: '=' : 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(166): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'FirstName'
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(166): error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(167): warning C4047: '=' : 'char [21]' differs in levels of indirection from 'char'
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(167): error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
1>c:\[....]\meg4545.c(174): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>

1>Time Elapsed 00:00:02.31

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: tempLast = LastName[j]; I am attempting to pass the last name string to a variable in order to reorder the array.

Comment: best if you condensed your code to only show the part that isn't working.

Comment: I had 2 open brackets in 2 for loops that I had failed to close.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure once I fix these that my program will function" -- all programmers believe this. All of them are mistaken. Break yourself of that habit of thought now, while you're still young.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, and I will take it to heart. I've gotten the program to run, but it crashes when passing from the menu function to the print records function but I think I've figured out why. I'm going to reorganize my code so that the menu function exists in main because it was not a requirement for the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem of probably many:

You have an array of `char` arrays (`LastName[][21]`) here:

```
void searchLast(char FirstName[][21],char LastName[][21], float Scores[],int NumOfRecords)
{
    ...
}
```

You're trying to copy `char` arrays here:

```
LastName[j] = LastName[k];
```

This is not how you copy strings in C.  You must do something like this:

```
strncpy(LastName[j], LastName[k], 21);
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention: in C, `char` arrays become strings if they are `NULL` (`'\0'`) terminated.  You must pass strings to `strncpy` for it to work properly.

Comment: So if I am going to do a string copy, I need to set my temp array up to accept as a char array, then string copy between those two in the reorder?

        'char TempLast[1][21];
        int x = 0;
        strncpy(TempLast[x],LastName[j],21);'

Comment: Thank you that eliminated a large number of my errors.